# Animating a group of children in a viewgroup

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-view

I'm working on a custom ViewGroup.

This ViewGroup has a bunch of children. I need to animate a few and change their position. I understand that Android animations move just the bitmap and not the real object. I've been trying to MOVE them by following various resources but have failed.

**What I'm doing with ViewGroup so far:**

1. Measure children and the ViewGroup
2. Position children in onLayout

**What I'm trying to do further**

Use a custom animation to move a small subset of the children. I'm using a custom Animation object because I need to move a bunch of Views and I'm applying translationX on all of them together. The other option that I know is to start a separate Animation on all of them and the thought of which makes me think it's gonna be unoptimized.

**Problem**

Views animate fine, but their real position remains unchanged. So the next time I'm trying to do the same kind of animation, but on the new co-ordinates, it doesn't work. Because, their positions haven't updated.

**What did I try**

1. Use `onAnimationEnd` to `layout` each of the children to the new left, top, right and bottom position. All views vanished
2. On `onAnimationEnd`, reset `translationX` to zero and then start re-positioning the views. No effect of calling `view.setTranslationX(0f)`

Can someone please help me with the correct way of doing this? Thanks

Comment: try to use [ObjectAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html) and it's support [library](http://nineoldandroids.com/) for below API 11...

Comment: you call manually child.layout(): right? so when animating do it as well

Comment: Have you tried Animation.setFillAfter?

Comment: @GopalRao I cannot use ObjectAnimator because I'm trying to apply animation transformation on a bunch of objects. Even though, I tried and its the same result

Comment: @dpk Animation.setFillAfter does the same thing. It doesn't move the object but moves it's bitmap and doesn't clear the bitmap after animation ends.

Comment: @pskink I could swear I tried this too earlier, but your idea worked. If you want to put it as an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: I would recommend to first just change the position of your child views and then listen for onPreDrawListener() and start you animations in there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when animating call layout() on your child Views

Comment: isn't calling layout() during the animation quite expensive?

Comment: this solved the problem, however I changed my entire implementation later to use translationX and then simply layout at final location on animation end